# In pandas, how to reindex(fill 0) in level 2 in multiindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, multi-index, reindex

I have a dataframe pivot table with 2 level of index: month and rating. The rating should be 1,2,3 (not to be confused with the columns 1,2,3). I found that for some months, the rating could be missing. E.g, (Population and 2021-10) only has rating 1,2. I need every month to have ratings 1,2,3. So I need to fill 0 for the missing rating index.

```py
        tbl = pd.pivot_table(self.df, values=['ID'], index=['month', 'risk'],
                             columns=["Factor"], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
        tbl = tbl.droplevel(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(index={'month': None,
                                                                                       'Risk': 'Client Risk Rating'})

# show Low for rating 1, Moderate for rating 2, Potential High for rating 3
    rating = {1: 'Low',
              2: 'Moderate',
              3: 'Potential High'
              }
    pop = {'N': 'Refreshed Clients', 'Y': 'Population'}
        tbl.rename(index={**rating,**pop}, inplace=True)
        tbl = tbl.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',', '')).astype(np.int64)
        tbl = tbl.div(tbl.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
        # client risk rating may be missing (e.g., only 1,2). 
        # To draw, need to fill the missing client risk rating with 0 
        print("before",tbl)
        tbl=tbl.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(tbl.index.levels), fill_value=0)
        print("after pd.MultiIndex.from_product",tbl)
```

I have used pd.MultiIndex.from_product. It does not work when all data is missing one index. For example, population has Moderate, 2021-03 and 2021-04 have Low and Moderate. After pd.MultiIndex.from_product, population has Low and Moderate, but all are missing High. My question is to have every month with risk 1,2,3. It seems the index values are from data.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't include your data as picture. Do include code to generate your data, especially for multiIndex data, e.g. `df.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` to create a full index:

```
>>> df
                             1         2         3
(Population)       1  0.436954  0.897747  0.387058
                   2  0.464940  0.611953  0.133941
2021-08(Refreshed) 1  0.496111  0.282798  0.048384
                   2  0.163582  0.213310  0.504647
                   3  0.008980  0.651175  0.400103

>>> df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels), fill_value=0)
                             1         2         3
(Population)       1  0.436954  0.897747  0.387058
                   2  0.464940  0.611953  0.133941
                   3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  # New record
2021-08(Refreshed) 1  0.496111  0.282798  0.048384
                   2  0.163582  0.213310  0.504647
                   3  0.008980  0.651175  0.400103
```

**Update**

> I wonder `df=df.reindex([1,2,3],level='rating',fill_value=0)` doesn't work because the new index values [1,2,3] cannot fill the missing values for the previous rating index. By using the from_product, it creates the product of two index.

In fact it works. I mean it has an effect but not the one you expect. The method reindex the **level** not the **values**. Let me show you:

```
# It seems there is not effect because you don't see 3 and 4 as expected?
>>> df.reindex([1, 2, 3, 4], level='ratings')
                                   0         1         2
                   ratings                              
(Population)       1        0.536154  0.671380  0.839362
                   2        0.729484  0.512379  0.440018
2021-08(Refreshed) 1        0.279990  0.295757  0.405536
                   2        0.864217  0.798092  0.144219
                   3        0.214566  0.407581  0.736905

# But yes something happens
>>> df.reindex([1, 2, 3, 4], level='ratings').index.levels
FrozenList([['(Population)', '2021-08(Refreshed)'], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
                              The level has been reindexed ---^

# It's different from values
>>> df.reindex([1, 2, 3, 4], level='ratings').index.get_level_values('ratings')
Int64Index([1, 2, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='ratings')
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much. I wonder df=df.reindex([1,2,3],level='rating',fill_value=0) doesn't work because the new index values [1,2,3] cannot fill the missing values for the previous rating index. By using the from_product, it creates the product of two index.

Comment: @Summer. I updated my answer with an explanation. I hope it's clearer now?

Comment: Thank you!!! I've used pd.MultiIndex.from_product to create a full index. It worked for different cases. But one case still missed one index value.  In your code example, that is  population 3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  # New record. Do you know the possible reason for this?

Comment: If you use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` as suggested, it should be not possible to miss a combination. Do you have an example?

Comment: Hi Corralien, I've edited my question with code and example. Basically speaking, when all data is missing rate 3, even after ```python pd.MultiIndex.from_product```, all data is missing rate 3.

Comment: As you already know the values for the second level, you can use `df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], rating.values()]), fill_value=0)`